Changing array elements by indexing
I have a list/array which has elements which need to be changed now and then. I changed elements in the list by indexing, and when I print out the list, it the changes have been made.
l = stdarray.create2D(width,height,"c")
l[0][5] = "d"
l[3][4] = "A"
l[2][6] = "D"

the output I get from printing it out is this:
[['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'D'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'A', 'c', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'], ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']]
which is what I expect.
However when I use the list elsewhere (in another function) the original list (with c only) is used as though I didn't make any changes, this is the entirety of the code
global l
l = stdarray.create2D(width,height,"c")
l[0][5] = "d"
l[3][4] = "A"
l[2][6] = "D"
#stdio.write(l)
i = 0

        for a in range(len(l)):
            for b in range(len(l[a])):
                piece = l[a][b]


I get a board with c's only as though I did not change the contents of the list.
I don't understand what my problem is currently.
Can you just give me hints as to what I did wrong

What is stdarray ? Also, there's nothing in your second code fragment that would cause your "array" to be modified

stdarray is the module I used to create a 2d array like the one printed out after the 1st code fragment

After creating your 2D "array" there are 3 explicit assignments to it. Subsequently there is no code that would cause the list contents to be altered. You haven't explained what changes you're expecting in the list. The assignment to piece is pointless as you never do anything with it

The only thing I can see that may be wrong about your code without the proper context is the variable piece. You may be changing piece somewhere within your code which does not change the actual matrix or changing l[a][b] after assigning piece and then printing out the old piece still.
Without the rest of the code I can't really help you.

I edited it and added the rest of the code

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I sort of figured it out, or rather, I found where my error is. I tried changing l[9][9] = b, and printed it out and the board had b's only. Meaning I made a mistake in my loop and 'piece' refers to l[9][9] only and I was not looping through l. So my program was using one object l[9][9] in the list and not all the objects in the list.
I guess using a list with different objects (instead of one with c's only) would have helped me see this sooner

Okay now I managed to fix everything and my code looks simpler. For some reason I was looping through the list too much (like 4 times).

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Could you please post the full code you used? I've tested it out with what I believe is the stdarray.create2D function that you're using- you forgot to include that!
(I suspect that the issue arises from your use of a variable 'piece' rather than a reference to a new array or other data structure. That suggests that either you're overwriting it at the wrong time, or that your code is simply not doing what you think it is.)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
